# How to retrieve Vector<Integer> value from Hashmap<String, Vector<Integer>>

Tags: java, android, vector, hashmap

I am writing an Android application to track recommended supplements resulting from a test. I've run into difficulty retrieving the Vector value that I stored in a HashMap<String, Vector> variable. I wrote some bypass functions to bypass the test so I could work on the results display. Here is my code:

```
private void skipTestSession() {
    sessionMap = createSessionMap();

    Intent iResults = new Intent(this, ResultsPage.class);
    iResults.putExtra("sessionMap", sessionMap);
    startActivity(iResults);
}

private HashMap<String, Vector<Integer>> createSessionMap() {
    HashMap<String, Vector<Integer>> sessionMap = new HashMap<>();
    String[] titles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.titles_array);
    for (int i = 1; i < titles.length; i++){
        Vector<Integer> supCodes = new Vector<Integer>();
        for(int iCode = 0; iCode < supMap.get(titles[i]).length; iCode++) {
            supCodes.add(supMap.get(titles[i])[iCode]);
        }
        sessionMap.put(titles[i], supCodes);
    }
    return sessionMap;
}
```

supMap keeps track of which supplements should be recommended for each test and is created by this function:

```
private HashMap <String, Integer[]> createSupMap() {
    supMap = new HashMap<>();
    String[] tests = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.titles_array);
    supMap.put(tests[1], new Integer[] {1,2,3,4,5});
    supMap.put(tests[2], new Integer[] {1,2,3,4,5});
    supMap.put(tests[3], new Integer[] {2,6,7,31,32});
    supMap.put(tests[4], new Integer[] {1,9,11});
    supMap.put(tests[5], new Integer[] {8,9});
    supMap.put(tests[6], new Integer[] {8,9});
    supMap.put(tests[7], new Integer[] {8,9});
    supMap.put(tests[8], new Integer[] {10,9,11});
    supMap.put(tests[9], new Integer[] {12});
    supMap.put(tests[10], new Integer[] {13,14,9});
    supMap.put(tests[11], new Integer[] {1,9,11});
    supMap.put(tests[12], new Integer[] {15,11,16});
    supMap.put(tests[13], new Integer[] {17,16,9});
    supMap.put(tests[14], new Integer[] {17,18,9});
    supMap.put(tests[15], new Integer[] {17,19,18});
    supMap.put(tests[16], new Integer[] {20,21,9});
    supMap.put(tests[17], new Integer[] {22,23,9});
    supMap.put(tests[18], new Integer[] {22,23,9});
    supMap.put(tests[19], new Integer[] {22,23,9});
    supMap.put(tests[20], new Integer[] {1,9,11});
    supMap.put(tests[21], new Integer[] {24,25,9});
    supMap.put(tests[22], new Integer[] {26,9,1,27});
    supMap.put(tests[23], new Integer[] {26,24,9});
    supMap.put(tests[24], new Integer[] {26,1,9});
    supMap.put(tests[25], new Integer[] {26,22,23});
    supMap.put(tests[26], new Integer[] {26,11,9});
    supMap.put(tests[27], new Integer[] {20,17,28});
    supMap.put(tests[28], new Integer[] {20,17,28});
    supMap.put(tests[29], new Integer[] {29,20,17,14});
    supMap.put(tests[30], new Integer[] {20});
    supMap.put(tests[31], new Integer[] {20,17});
    supMap.put(tests[32], new Integer[] {20,17});
    supMap.put(tests[33], new Integer[] {4,5});
    return supMap;
}
```

These integers map to the supplement names in another StringArray in the strings.xml file. The supplement names are registered trademarks and I'm not sure how the laws work for that so I'll share the array with coded supplement names.

```
    <string-array name="supplement_list">
    <item></item>
    <item>Supplement 1</item>
    <item>Supplement 2</item>
    <item>Supplement 3</item>
    <item>Supplement 4</item>
    <item>Supplement 5</item>
    <item>Supplement 6</item>
    <item>Supplement 7</item>
    <item>Supplement 8</item>
    <item>Supplement 9</item>
    <item>Supplement 10</item>
    <item>Supplement 11</item>
    <item>Supplement 12</item>
    <item>Supplement 13</item>
    <item>Supplement 14</item>
    <item>Supplement 15</item>
    <item>Supplement 16</item>
    <item>Supplement 17</item>
    <item>Supplement 18</item>
    <item>Supplement 19</item>
    <item>Supplement 20</item>
    <item>Supplement 21</item>
    <item>Supplement 22</item>
    <item>Supplement 23</item>
    <item>Supplement 24</item>
    <item>Supplement 25</item>
    <item>Supplement 26</item>
    <item>Supplement 27</item>
    <item>Supplement 28</item>
    <item>Supplement 29</item>
    <item>Supplement 30</item>
    <item>Supplement 31</item>
    <item>Supplement 32</item>
</string-array>
```

Here is the code from the Results page:

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.ScrollView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Vector;

public class ResultsPage extends AppCompatActivity {
HashMap<String, Vector<Integer>> sessionMap;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_results_page);

    Intent i = getIntent();
    sessionMap = (HashMap<String, Vector<Integer>>) i.getSerializableExtra("sessionMap");
    Log.i("status","After initializing SessionMap");

    displayResults();
}

private void displayResults(){
    String resultsString = "Your imbalances with recommended supplements \n\n";
    String[] supNames = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.supplement_list);
    String[] imbalances = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.titles_array);

    for (int i = 1; i < imbalances.length; i++) {
        if(sessionMap.containsKey(imbalances[i])) {
            resultsString += imbalances[i] + "\n";

            Vector<Integer> supCodes = sessionMap.get(imbalances[i]);

            for(int iCode = 0; iCode < supCodes.size(); iCode++) {
                resultsString += "\t\t" + supNames[(int) supCodes.get(iCode)] + "\n";
            }
            resultsString += "\n";
        }
    }

    TextView resultsView = new TextView(this);
    resultsView.setText(resultsString);
    ScrollView scrollView = findViewById(R.id.scroll);
    scrollView.addView(resultsView);
}
}
```

The problem right now is the line that says:

```
Vector<Integer> supCodes = sessionMap.get(imbalances[i]);
```

When the program tries to execute this line it crashes. I couldn't figure out how to change the color of the error portion to red so I added a row of //// where the red began. Here is the debug console output:

```
01/14 16:48:37: Launching 'app' on Nexus 5X API 24.
$ adb shell am start -n "com.lareescott.pdfexample/com.lareescott.pdfexample.MainActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER -D
Connecting to com.lareescott.pdfexample
Waiting for application to come online: com.lareescott.pdfexample | com.lareescott.pdfexample.test
Connected to process 12574 on device 'emulator-5554'.
Connecting to com.lareescott.pdfexample
Waiting for application to start debug server
Connected to the target VM, address: 'localhost:8696', transport: 'socket'
Capturing and displaying logcat messages from application. This behavior can be disabled in the "Logcat output" section of the "Debugger" settings page.
I/art: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
W/art: Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using defaults: x86
W/ActivityThread: Application com.lareescott.pdfexample is waiting for the debugger on port 8100...
I/System.out: Sending WAIT chunk
I/art: Debugger is active
I/System.out: Debugger has connected
    waiting for debugger to settle...
I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
I/System.out: debugger has settled (1366)
W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.lareescott.pdfexample-1/lib/x86
W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter androidx.vectordrawable.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<androidx.core.view.ViewCompat$2>: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/view/View$OnUnhandledKeyEventListener;
        at void androidx.core.view.ViewCompat.setBackground(android.view.View, android.graphics.drawable.Drawable) (ViewCompat.java:2678)
        at void androidx.appcompat.widget.ActionBarContainer.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet) (ActionBarContainer.java:63)
        at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0!(java.lang.Object[]) (Constructor.java:-2)
        at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(java.lang.Object[]) (Constructor.java:430)
        at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, android.util.AttributeSet) (LayoutInflater.java:645)
        at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(android.view.View, java.lang.String, android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:787)
        at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(android.view.View, java.lang.String, android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet) (LayoutInflater.java:727)
        at void android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser, android.view.View, android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:858)
        at void android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser, android.view.View, android.util.AttributeSet, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:821)
        at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser, android.view.ViewGroup, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:518)
        at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(int, android.view.ViewGroup, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:426)
        at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(int, android.view.ViewGroup) (LayoutInflater.java:377)
        at android.view.ViewGroup androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createSubDecor() (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:896)
        at void androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.ensureSubDecor() (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:806)
        at void androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(int) (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:693)
        at void androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(int) (AppCompatActivity.java:170)
        at void com.lareescott.pdfexample.MainActivity.onCreate(android.os.Bundle) (MainActivity.java:35)
I/art:     at void android.app.Activity.performCreate(android.os.Bundle) (Activity.java:6662)
        at void android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(android.app.Activity, android.os.Bundle) (Instrumentation.java:1118)
        at android.app.Activity android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent) (ActivityThread.java:2599)
        at void android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:2707)
        at void android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(android.app.ActivityThread, android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:-1)
        at void android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(android.os.Message) (ActivityThread.java:1460)
        at void android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(android.os.Message) (Handler.java:102)
        at void android.os.Looper.loop() (Looper.java:154)
        at void android.app.ActivityThread.main(java.lang.String[]) (ActivityThread.java:6077)
        at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke!(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object[]) (Method.java:-2)
        at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() (ZygoteInit.java:866)
I/art:     at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(java.lang.String[]) (ZygoteInit.java:756)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.view.View$OnUnhandledKeyEventListener" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.lareescott.pdfexample-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.lareescott.pdfexample-1/lib/x86, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
        at java.lang.Class dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(java.lang.String) (BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
        at java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(java.lang.String, boolean) (ClassLoader.java:380)
        at java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(java.lang.String) (ClassLoader.java:312)
        at void androidx.core.view.ViewCompat.setBackground(android.view.View, android.graphics.drawable.Drawable) (ViewCompat.java:2678)
        at void androidx.appcompat.widget.ActionBarContainer.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet) (ActionBarContainer.java:63)
        at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0!(java.lang.Object[]) (Constructor.java:-2)
        at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(java.lang.Object[]) (Constructor.java:430)
        at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, android.util.AttributeSet) (LayoutInflater.java:645)
I/art:     at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(android.view.View, java.lang.String, android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:787)
        at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(android.view.View, java.lang.String, android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet) (LayoutInflater.java:727)
        at void android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser, android.view.View, android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:858)
        at void android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser, android.view.View, android.util.AttributeSet, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:821)
        at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser, android.view.ViewGroup, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:518)
        at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(int, android.view.ViewGroup, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:426)
        at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(int, android.view.ViewGroup) (LayoutInflater.java:377)
        at android.view.ViewGroup androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createSubDecor() (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:896)
        at void androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.ensureSubDecor() (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:806)
        at void androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(int) (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:693)
        at void androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(int) (AppCompatActivity.java:170)
        at void com.lareescott.pdfexample.MainActivity.onCreate(android.os.Bundle) (MainActivity.java:35)
        at void android.app.Activity.performCreate(android.os.Bundle) (Activity.java:6662)
        at void android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(android.app.Activity, android.os.Bundle) (Instrumentation.java:1118)
        at android.app.Activity android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent) (ActivityThread.java:2599)
        at void android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:2707)
        at void android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(android.app.ActivityThread, android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:-1)
        at void android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(android.os.Message) (ActivityThread.java:1460)
        at void android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(android.os.Message) (Handler.java:102)
        at void android.os.Looper.loop() (Looper.java:154)
        at void android.app.ActivityThread.main(java.lang.String[]) (ActivityThread.java:6077)
        at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke!(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object[]) (Method.java:-2)
        at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() (ZygoteInit.java:866)
        at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(java.lang.String[]) (ZygoteInit.java:756)
D/: HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xa7a73e40, tid 12574
D/: HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0x90a3f500, tid 12617
I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 1
W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to choose config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without...
D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 0
D/EGL_emulation: eglCreateContext: 0xab6853c0: maj 2 min 0 rcv 2
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xab6853c0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xab6831c0)
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xab6853c0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xab6831c0)
I/status: After initializing SessionMap
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
//////////////////////////////////////////////
    E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        Process: com.lareescott.pdfexample, PID: 12574
        java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.lareescott.pdfexample/com.lareescott.pdfexample.ResultsPage}: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to java.util.Vector
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2646)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
         Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to java.util.Vector
            at com.lareescott.pdfexample.ResultsPage.displayResults(ResultsPage.java:39)
            at com.lareescott.pdfexample.ResultsPage.onCreate(ResultsPage.java:27)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6662)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2599)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707) 
            at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460) 
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077) 
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866) 
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756) 
    Disconnected from the target VM, address: 'localhost:8696', transport: 'socket'
```

I can't make any sense of it. Here is the XML code for the results page in case you need it.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ResultsPage">

    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/titleText"
    android:layout_width="346dp"
    android:layout_height="45dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-black"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:text="Results"
    android:textSize="36sp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scroll"
    android:layout_width="396dp"
    android:layout_height="511dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/titleText">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" />
</ScrollView>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="128dp"
    android:layout_height="56dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:text="Save to PDF"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button2"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:text="Send to Email"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" /></androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I originally had sessionMap as a HashMap<String, Integer[]> just like supMap, however the difficulty was that I don't know how many integers I need to store before the user clicks their checkboxes so I don't know how big to make the arrays so I thought a vector would work better. I need help figuring out how to retrieve the vector value so I can use it or I need advice on a better data structure to use.

This is the first major project I've done in Java. I spent hours searching online for a solution but have not had any luck. If you have questions or need more information please let me know. Your time and assistance is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: There seems a classCastException in the line you pointed:   `Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to java.util.Vector`

Comment: Okay I see that now but why would it say that I don't have any ArrayLists. I don't know how to fix it.